# Moving gameObject from A to B

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to animate / transform a gameObject `movingObject` from it's spawn position to the `destination`. I believe the issue is somewhere in the implementation of the `IncrementPosition` function.

Rather than moving the one cube from A to B. The script spawns multiple cubes until it gets to B. Can you see where I'm going wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class onClickSpawnMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public GameObject randomSpawn;

    private GameObject movingObject;
    private Vector3 destination;

    void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        SetDestination(movingObject.transform.position);
        if (destination != movingObject.transform.position) {
            IncrementPosition();
        }
    }

    void IncrementPosition()
    {

        float delta = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 currentPosition = movingObject.transform.position;
        Vector3 nextPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPosition, destination, delta);

        movingObject.transform.position = nextPosition;
    }

    void Spawn() {
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
        movingObject = Instantiate(randomSpawn, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void SetDestination(Vector3 value)
    {
        destination = new Vector3(20, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe your speed variable is set to 0 in unity editor?

Comment: And why don't you use AnimatorController/Animation for making your animation without any need for writing script?

Comment: @omid the location of B will always be random

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @shingo rather than moving the one cube from A to B. The script spawns multiple cubes until it gets to B

Comment: Please remove commented lines.

Comment: I think the script will spawn `randomSpawn` only once except the **Spawn / Start** method is called multiple times.

Comment: @shingo can you identify where Spawn / Start is being called?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to call the Spawn / Start method casually:

1. `gameObject.AddComponent<onClickSpawnMove>();` the Start method will be invoked again.
2. `Instantiate` a prefab that onClickSpawnMove script is attached already.
3. `gameObject.SendMessage("Start");` maybe, but rarely seen.

You can add a log or break point to check when the Spawn / Start method is called.

Print the hash code will help you know the different `onClickSpawnMove` instances.

And you can click the message in the console to know which `GameObject` is.

```
void Start()
{
    Spawn();
    Debug.Log("Start " + this.GetHashCode(), this);
}
```

Comment: So start is being repeatedly called, spawning lots of cubes. How do I spawn just one cube?

Comment: @RhysEdwards, first make sure why Start is called repeatedly.

Comment: @derHugo, I don't want to call Start, I'm listing probability of calling a method.indirectly

Comment: @shingo oh ya sorry now I understood that you are listing ways how it might be called unintentional ^^